# How to make dot (composition) and dollar (application) sign for functors?

Tags: haskell

I have made dot sign for functors (○), but my application (↯) doesnt work, I have an error in `test3` function declaration

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Protolude

-- composition of functors, analog of .
infixr 9 ○
type (○) f g a = f (g a)

-- functor application, analog of $
infixr 0 ↯
type (↯) f a = f a

test :: [] (Maybe Int)
test = [Just 1]

test2 :: ([] ○ Maybe) Int
test2 = [Just 1]

test3 :: ([] ○ Maybe) ↯ Int -- error here
test3 = [Just 1]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print test
  print test2
  return ()
```

I have an error

```
[Error]• The type synonym ‘○’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2 • In the type signature: test3 :: ([] ○ Maybe) ↯ Int
```

What's wrong?

---

UPDATE

Here is the implementation using newtype, because `type synonyms cannot be partially applied` (@M.Aroosi)

I don't like it because I have to wrap data with datatype constructor all the time

**Is there a way to implement it without need to wrap data with `Composition` or `Apply` all the time?**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Protolude

-- I can't use `type` here, because type synonyms cannot be partially applied

-- composition of functors, analog of .
infixr 9 ○
newtype (○) f g a = Composition (f (g a)) deriving (Show)

-- functor application, analog of $
infixr 0 ↯
newtype (↯) f a = Apply (f a) deriving (Show)

test :: [] (Maybe Int)
test = [Just 1]

test2 :: ([] ○ Maybe) Int
test2 = Composition [Just 1]

test2' :: [] ○ Maybe ↯ Int
test2' = Apply (Composition [Just 1])

test3 :: ([] ○ Maybe ○ Maybe) Int
test3 = Composition [Composition (Just (Just 1))]

test3' :: [] ○ Maybe ○ Maybe ↯ Int
test3' = Apply (Composition [Composition (Just (Just 1))])

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print test
  print test2
  print test2'
  print test3
  print test3'
  return ()
```

---

UPDATE

This can be done trivially in idris

```
module Main

test : List (Maybe Integer)
test = [Just 1]

-- using (.) from prelude
test1 : (List . Maybe) Integer
test1 = [Just 1]

-- using (.) and ($) from prelude
test2 : List . Maybe $ Integer
test2 = [Just 1]

main : IO ()
main = do
  print test
  print test1
  print test2
```

---

UPDATE

composition with `type` also works in purescript (YAY!)

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, logShow)

type Composition f g a = f (g a)
infixr 9 type Composition as ○

type Apply f a = f a
infixr 0 type Apply as ↯

test1 :: (Array ○ Maybe) Int
test1 = [Just 1]

test2 :: Array ○ Maybe ↯ Int
test2 = [Just 1]

test3 :: (Array ○ Maybe ○ Maybe) Int
test3 = [Just (Just 1)]

test4 :: Array ○ Maybe ○ Maybe ↯ Int
test4 = [Just (Just 1)]

main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
main = do
  logShow test1
  logShow test2
  logShow test3
  logShow test4
```

---

UPDATE

there is an ongoing effort to make this possible in haskell

https://github.com/kcsongor/typelevel-prelude

Comment: @M.Aroosi (I see you deleted your comment) very bad that `type synonyms cannot be partially applied`, code looks ugly when I have to wrap my object in datatype constructors `Compose` and `Apply` each time (posted an answer). Is there a way to implement compositions of functors without `data` or `newtype`?

Comment: Is there a way to implement compositions of functors without need to wrap in data constructor `Composition` or `Apply` all the time? Is this possible to make this with type synonyms in idris for example?

Comment: There is sort of a solution with type families and whatnot, but it involves using type signatures like `Eval ([] ○ Maybe ○ Lift Maybe ↯ Int)`, or if you prefer to introduce another operator for the last(well, first since it associates to the right) composition: `Eval ([] ○ Maybe % Maybe ↯ Int)` If this fits with what you want, tell me and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @M. Aroosi yes, please, post an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as per your request, here's the solution involving type families. It is based around the idea behind the [`Fcf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/first-class-families-0.3.0.1/docs/Fcf.html) package with an article explaining that idea [here](http://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-08-06-one-type-family.html)

Before I begin there's something in favor of using a normal data type/newtype: You can define functor instances for the composition type so it acts as a single unit, that is you can define `instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where ..` which you can't do with the approach below.
There might be a library that allows you to do that with a list of types instead of just 2 (so something like `Compose [Maybe, [], Either Int] a`), but I can't seem to find it right now, so if anyone knows it it's probably a better solution than the one I present below (in my opinion).

First we need some language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
  TypeFamilies,
  TypeInType,
  TypeOperators
  #-}
```

Let's also include `Data.Kind` for `Type`

```
import Data.Kind (Type)
```

Let's define a type `Exp a` which will represent `a`.
We'll also define a type family `Eval` which will let do the grunt work, it will take an `Exp a` and give us an `a`

```
type Exp a = a -> Type
type family Eval (e :: Exp a) :: a
```

We can now define our operators `(○)` and `(↯)` (I'd prefer to use easier to type operators here, say # and $ instead, but I'll stick with the ones you picked for this answer).
We define these as empty data types. This is where `TypeInType` comes in (and `TypeOperators` but that's because we are using operators).

```
infixr 9 ○
data (○) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> Exp b) -> a -> Exp c

infixr 0 ↯
data (↯) :: (a -> Exp b) -> a -> Exp b
```

Notice how the final kind is `Exp a` for them? that allows us to give them type instances for `Eval`

```
type instance Eval ((○) f g a) = f (Eval (g a))
type instance Eval ((↯) f a) = Eval (f a)
```

Now you may be wondering "`(○)`'s second argument is of kind `a -> Exp b`, but I want to give it something like `Maybe` which has kind `* -> *`!", this is where we have 3 solutions to that problem:

1. add another operator, say `(%)` which is just like `(○)` but takes a second argument of kind `a -> b` instead of `a -> Exp b`. This only needs to replace the right-most composition operator.
2. "lift" the kind `a -> b` into `a -> Exp b`, I'll use a data type named `Lift` for that. This only needs to be done to the rightmost type in the composition.
3. provide a "do nothing" data type of kind `a -> Exp b`, I'll call that `Pure`.

Here are the three solutions written in Haskell:

```
infixr 9 %
data (%) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Exp c
type instance Eval ((%) f g a) = f (g a)

data Lift :: (a -> b) -> a -> Exp b
type instance Eval (Lift f a) = f a

data Pure :: a -> Exp a
type instance Eval (Pure a) = a
```

One more thing we can do with this setup is make a type-level function datatype we call "Compose" which will take a list of types and produce their composition

```
data Compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> Exp a 
type instance Eval (Compose '[] a) = a
type instance Eval (Compose (x:xs) a) = x (Eval (Compose xs a))
```

Now we can make our program, with some tests and a `main` that just prints the values of the tests:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
  TypeFamilies,
  TypeInType,
  TypeOperators
  #-}

module Main where

import Data.Kind (Type)

type Exp a = a -> Type
type family Eval (e :: Exp a) :: a

infixr 9 ○
data (○) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> Exp b) -> a -> Exp c

infixr 0 ↯
data (↯) :: (a -> Exp b) -> a -> Exp b

type instance Eval ((○) f g a) = f (Eval (g a))
type instance Eval ((↯) f a) = Eval (f a)

infixr 9 %
data (%) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Exp c
type instance Eval ((%) f g a) = f (g a)

data Lift :: (a -> b) -> a -> Exp b
type instance Eval (Lift f a) = f a

data Pure :: a -> Exp a
type instance Eval (Pure a) = a 

data Compose :: [a -> a] -> a -> Exp a 
type instance Eval (Compose '[] a) = a
type instance Eval (Compose (x:xs) a) = x (Eval (Compose xs a))

test :: [] (Maybe Int)
test = [Just 1]

-- using %
test2 :: Eval (([] % Maybe) Int)
test2 = [Just 1]

test2' :: Eval ([] % Maybe ↯ Int)
test2' = [Just 1]

-- works for longer types too
test3 :: Eval (([] ○ Maybe % Maybe) Int)
test3 = [Just (Just 1)]

test3' :: Eval ([] ○ Maybe % Maybe ↯ Int)
test3' = [Just (Just 1)]

-- we can instead Lift the rightmost type
test4 :: Eval (([] ○ Maybe ○ Lift Maybe) Int)
test4 = [Just (Just 1)]

test4' :: Eval ([] ○ Maybe ○ Lift Maybe ↯ Int)
test4' = [Just (Just 1)]

-- an even longer type, with definition "matching" the type declaration
test5 :: Eval ([] ○ Maybe ○ Either Bool % Maybe ↯ Int)
test5 = (:[]) . Just . Right . Just $ 1

-- Same as above, but instead let's use Pure so we don't need to lift the Maybe or use %
test6 :: Eval ([] ○ Maybe ○ Either Bool ○ Maybe ○ Pure ↯ Int)
test6= (:[]) . Just . Right . Just $ 1

-- same as above, uses Compose
test7 :: Eval (Compose [[], Maybe, Either Bool, Maybe] Int)
test7= (:[]) . Just . Right . Just $ 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print test
  print test2
  print test2'
  print test3
  print test3'
  print test4
  print test4'
  print test5
  print test6
  print test7
  return ()
```

Comment: One thing I'd like to add, is that the `Fcf` package defines most of those things already, You'd only need to add a few of the things in the answer: the composition operator, the application operator if you want that unicode lightning (there's already one in `Fcf`, they just use `($)` for it), the `%` operator if you want it. In `Fcf` they called what I named `Lift` as `Pure1`, you could also use the fish operator `<=<` instead of defining your own composition, but then you'd need to stick `Pure1` on everything.

Comment: unexpected answer for common problem, tnx